# I am 22 years old and I plan on moving to Canada in the future. What should I do?

Tags: canada

I am 22 years old and I will be graduating from university in Computer Science in 2013. I went to Canada for one year for a gap year and I absolutely love that place. I know I am only 22 years old and I'm a bit young thinking about immigrating to another country already but I really do love Canada. I feel like that's where I belong, I feel at home there.

I will be graduating next year so I will have be lacking in experience in many areas. What would be the best way to apply for residency in Canada? Should I stay in the UK for a couple of years and gain some work experience and then apply through the skilled workers route? Or should I go through the IEC program, spend one year there with a Working Holiday Permit and use that time to hopefully find a job that will sponsor me?

Comment: I think this would be more appropriate for this site: http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/10331/immigration

Comment: Immigration questions are explicitly off-topic, see the [FAQ](http://travel.stackexchange.com/faq).

Comment: The right place to ask questions about immigration is [Expatriates](http://expatriates.stackexchange.com)